# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: libcurl

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, i386, ios-frameworks

While i am integrating libcurl, getting the following issue.
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
 "_SSLClose", referenced from:
  _Curl_darwinssl_close in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
"_SSLCopyPeerTrust", referenced from:
  _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
"_SSLCreateContext", referenced from:
  _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
  _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
  _Curl_darwinssl_close in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o)
"_SSLGetBufferedReadSize", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static library that you have added `libcurl.a` is meant for device. you are trying to build your application for simulator (i386 is for Mac). Either change your `libcurl.a` or build your application for Device would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I once ran this an issue like this with another library. The problem is that the simulator runs on an x86 processor and the actual device is on ARM, you actually need two separate builds of the library in the project. One for the simulator and one for ARM. If you are targeting ARM-64, you will need a build for it too.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in your Run Script... Hope this will fix

## define output folder environment variable

```
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
```

## Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions

```
xcodebuild -target GEOAuthAuthentication ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target GEOAuthAuthentication -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target GEOAuthAuthentication -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" TARGET_BUILD_DIR="./build-x86_64"
```

## make sure the output directory exists

```
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
```

## Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo

```
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "./build-x86_64/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"
```

## Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience

```
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Targets->Build Phases-> Link Binary With Labraries is all required frameworks and libraries added